# How to check if part of string is present in array or not

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have got of array symbols as shown below

```
var sourcesymbols = ["ERT", "UBL" , "AMAZING"];
```

I am getting the following news title from rss feed

**you experts are amazing**

How to check if the content present in the rssfeedstring is present under the **sourcesymbols** array or not ??

For example rssfeedstring  has word **amazing** and it is also present under **sourcesymbols**

please let me know how to achive this .

I have tried to convert the rssfeedstring to uppercase then i am not sure how to use the indexOf on the string .

```
rssfeedstring = rssfeedstring.toUpperCase();
```

please let em know if there is any better approach also for doing this as the array will have 2000 symbols

http://jsfiddle.net/955pfz01/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex.

Steps:

1. Convert the array to string with `join` using `|`(OR in regex) as *glue*
2. Use `\b`-word boundary to match exact words
3. Use `i` flag on regex to match irrespective of the case. So, don't have to change the case of string.
4. Escape the slashes as using `RegExp` constructor requires string to be passed and `\` in string is used as escape following character.
5. `test` can be used on regex to check if the string passes the regex.

```js
var sourcesymbols = ["ERT", "UBL", "AMAZING"];
var mystr = 'you experts are amazing';

var regex = new RegExp("\\b(" + sourcesymbols.join('|') + ")\\b", 'i'); // /\b(ERT|UBL|AMAZING)\b/i

alert(regex.test(mystr));
```

---

You can also use [**some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

1. Convert the string to array by using `split` with `\s+`. This will split the string by any(spaces, tabs, etc) one or more space character
2. Use `some` on splitted array
3. Convert the string to uppercase for comparing
4. Check if the element is present in array using `indexOf`

```js
var mystr = 'you experts are amazing';
var sourcesymbols = ["ERT", "UBL", "AMAZING"];

var present = mystr.toUpperCase().split(/\s+/).some(function(e) {
  return sourcesymbols.indexOf(e) > -1;
});

alert(present);
```

Comment: Could you please let me provide a example .

Comment: FYI to OP this will match BERT.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for pointing out. Used `\b` word boundary

Comment: @Tushar , could you please look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tp11h9yv/4/ , why am i getting true in this case ??

Comment: @PreethiJain Please check http://jsfiddle.net/nmgxw2c4/, missed `()`, updating answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Array.prototype.map()` , `Array.prototype.indexOf()` to return matched text, index of matched text within `sourcesymbols`

```
var sourcesymbols = ["ERT", "UBL" , "AMAZING"]; 

var mystr = 'you experts are amazing';

var res = mystr.split(" ").map(function(val, index) {
  var str = val.toUpperCase(), i = sourcesymbols.indexOf(str);
  return i !== -1 ? [val, i] : null
}).filter(Boolean);

console.log(res)
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/955pfz01/6/

Comment: Updated your code http://jsfiddle.net/8nsz1goj/. Feel free to update answer, if this improves code